# Node.js and Mocha unit testing rollback transaction after each test

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, transactions, mocha.js

I'm using `node v10.16.0` and npm packages `mssql 5.1.0` and `mocha 6.2.1`.
What I want to do is write a sql unit test helper class (ES6) that handles transactions and rolls back after each unit test.

**db.js**

```
const mssql  = require("mssql");
const config = require("./config");

class DbAccess{
    constructor(){
        this.connection = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config.dbConfig);

        this.connection.connect(err => {
        // ...
        })

        this.transaction = new mssql.Transaction(this.connection);

    }

    beginTransaction(){
        this.transaction.begin();
    }


    rollbackTransaction(){
        this.transaction.rollback();
    }


    executeSql (sql, callback) {
        this.connection.connect().then(() => {
            var req = new mssql.Request(conn);          
            req.query(sql).then((recordset) => {
                callback(recordset);
            })
        .catch ((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            logger.error(err);
            callback(null, err);
        });})
        .catch ((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            logger.error(err);
            callback(null, err);
        });
    }
}
```

**test.js**

```
before(() => {
    dbAccess.beginTransaction();
});

after(() => {
    dbAccess.rollbackTransaction();
});
describe('Test',function(){    
    describe('SelectAll()', function(){
        it('returns all',function(){                      
            dbAccess.insertrecords();                
        });
    });
});
```

That setup is not working as I'm getting a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.`

I can't figure out how to

1. Begin the transaction (in the before handler),
2. Execute the sql queries (in the test, e.g. inserting records),
3. Rollback the transaction (in the after handler)

Comment: I played with promises and observables but how does that work with having a transaction start and end in a different place? All examples I see is transaction begin and rollback in a single block. It must be possible somehow, no?

Comment: There are two things that seems odd to me, 1. You need to instantiate the db.js so that your connect to DB gets open. 2. These DB functions are normally async, so may be you want to use async/awit

Comment: Points taken. Could you elaborate more on that? 1. I'm not from a JS background so I perhaps put stuff in classes where I don't need to. What is another way? 2. that seems to be crucial. I can return a promise in the before to take care of that if I understand correctly.